# How to get Confidence Interval For One Point On Regression Line using python?

Tags: python, regression, confidence-interval, lower-bound, upperbound

How do I get the CI for one point on the regression line?I am using statsmodels library OLS function for my analysis. I am trying to draw the upper and lower bound of the confidence interval for one point first then draw it for all points of the regression line eventually